# #1044 - Access denied for user 'someusr'@'localhost' to database 'somedb'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, boomi

I'm trying to give admin rights to MySQL user using this SQL statement ran on cpanel>phpmyadmin>SQL

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON somedb.* TO 'someusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but it's giving user denied error:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'someusr'@'localhost' to database 'somedb'
```

We are trying to Integrate our website "www.somewebsite.com" MySQL database with Peachtree accounting software using Dell Boomi AtomSphere.

As per Dell Boomi forums. They replied in the link.

https://community.boomi.com/message/8983

There is no global privileges option on the phpMyAdmin page. There is only data and structure privileges in Cpanel>MySQL Database but no Administration privileges as shown in this video @ 8:27 sec;
https://youtu.be/64nYbTkcRZ4?t=507

I tried using SHOW GRANTS FOR 'someusr'@'localhost';

It's showing:

Grants for someusr@localhost

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someusr'@'localhost'
IS GRANTABLE = NO

What should I do?

Comment: grant usage means that that use can login and just about nothing else

Comment: maybe the issue is that *you* are logged in as the user you are trying to grant priv to ... or as a user that lacks grant rights. So do a `select current_user();`

Comment: @Drew you mean I have to login to another user in Cpanel that have all the admin rights. I already asked the developer to give me the rights or different login name and password, he said that I already have all the admin rights but actually I don't and select current_user(); shows current_user() 'someusr'@'localhost';

Comment: if `select current_user()` shows 'someusr'@'localhost' ... the user that you appear to be trying to do the grants for, and show grants shows just usage, there is no way what you are doing this split second has a chance of working

Comment: So just share that info with that techie and he will probably patch it all up for you

Comment: It may be that you have to merely logout and get back it. Or have someone flush priv

Comment: Actually I already shared this info with that developer, he said that everything is fine and don't need these admin rights to do integration. Probably he's ignorant or don't want to help. So probably I'm stuck for now or maybe I need to purchase my own host and make everything from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps I can give you a testbed somewhere. Ping me later if you dont resolve it

Comment: OK provide it if you can. Can't resolve anything for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121371/discussion-between-user3259951-and-drew).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there are two steps to solve this problem if you are using Cpanel.
First step is to go to Remote MySQL and add your IP address of your network.You can check your IP by going to whatismyipaddress.com or add % percent sign so that anyone can access it but this is not recommended because of security issues.
Secondly go to the MySQL Database and grant all user privileges like select, update, delete etc. Now you cannot get any user denied error using dell boomi.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming the database is already there):

```
CREATE USER 'someusr'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON somedb.* TO 'someusr'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Actually it didn't work. #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Yes, I assumed you had access since you're trying to give admin rights to someone else

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party ( again) but here is another simple solution that wworked for me in the same case :

Open the `*.sql` file in a text editor and change all instances of `old_db_name' to`new_cpanel_db_name'. and try to import again.

Most likely there will be only few occurences at the top of the file, something like :
`

```
--
-- Database: `old_db_name`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `old_db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `old_db_name`;
```

`

worked for me severaal times..